# Get Taskbar Position?

Tags: delphi, taskbar, system-tray

I have my main Application hidden using:

```
Application.ShowMainForm:= False;
```

The Application uses a TTrayIcon which I have assigned a Popup menu to.

By using and selecting one of the Popup menus in the Tray Icon I want to make my Application visible again, but I want the position of the Application to popup above the Taskbar.

By default the Windows Taskbar is at the bottom, so in this case my Application would appear in the bottom right just above the clock - of course the Taskbar can be moved and sized by the user so I need a way of knowing definitively these metrics.

Simply put, I want my Application to appear in the corner of the Taskbar above (or next) to the System clock.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The icon moves even when the task bar is fixed. New icons get added or removed. Icons can be hidden and then shown by the user.  Is it enough to know which corner of the screen it is closest to?

Comment: I guess Craig wants to mimic the behaviour of Windows Live Messenger, Windows Update, etc., which popup in the lower-right corner of the screen (at least if you got the notification area there -- since I always have it there, I don't know for sure how WLM and WU determine which corner to use).

Comment: @Andreas yeah you are kind of right, I wante either a message box or small form to popup near the taskbar corner/system tray area

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the location of the taskbar:

```
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, appBarData);
```

That, along with the size of the "primary" monitor:

```
nScreenWidth := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
nScreenHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

and you can work out if the **Taskbar** is located at the

- top
- left
- bottom
- right

of the screen, and its size.

```
{Calculate taskbar position from its window rect. However,
 on XP it may be that the taskbar is slightly larger or smaller than the
 screen size. Therefore we allow some tolerance here.
}
if NearlyEqual(rcTaskbar.Left, 0, TASKBAR_X_TOLERANCE) and
        NearlyEqual(rcTaskbar.Right, nScreenWidth, TASKBAR_X_TOLERANCE) then
begin
    // Taskbar is on top or on bottom
    if NearlyEqual(rcTaskbar.Top, 0, TASKBAR_Y_TOLERANCE) then
        FTaskbarPlacement := ABE_TOP
    else
        FTaskbarPlacement := ABE_BOTTOM;
end
else
begin
    // Taskbar is on left or on right
    if NearlyEqual(rcTaskbar.Left, 0, TASKBAR_X_TOLERANCE) then
        FTaskbarPlacement := ABE_LEFT
    else
        FTaskbarPlacement := ABE_RIGHT;
end;
```

With that you can pop up your toast:

```
case FTaskbarPlacement of
ABE_RIGHT:
   begin
      Self.Left := rcTaskbar.Left-Self.Width;
      Self.Top := rcTaskbar.Bottom - Self.Height;
   end;
ABE_LEFT:
   begin
      Self.Left := rcTaskbar.Right;
      Self.Top := rcTaskbar.Bottom - Self.Height;
   end;
 ABE_TOP:
    begin
       Self.Left := rcTaskbar.Right - Self.Height;
       Self.Top := rcTaskbar.Bottom;
    end;
 else //ABE_BOTTOM
    // Taskbar is on the bottom or Invisible
    Self.Left := rcTaskbar.Right - Self.Width;
    Self.Top := rcTaskbar.Top - Self.Height;
 end;
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is the *find the nearest* corner approach which I think is the best solution.  Attempting to locate the actual icon coords is just too hacks.

Comment: i read his question as wanting to know where the taskbar was - so he could pop up his application near the notification area (i.e. *toast*). i never knew there was an ability to get the location of the *icon* in the notification area. (Not that you really want to - it could be hidden or moved at any time)

Comment: The time you need to know a precise location is when you show a popup menu in response to right click but the message you receive contains coordinates. I think your reading of the question is correct.

Comment: You can just use uEdge to find the position of taskbar.
0 — Left, 1 — Top, 2 — Right, 3 — Bottom.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7 you can call [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378426%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

On earlier versions of Windows all you can do is to use rather grotesque hacks.

Comment: @Andreas I guess it was added to reduce the load on MSDN forums which asked questions that this API function can answer!

Answer (score -3):

Create a TForm at runtime

could also set AlphaBlendValue 0 for transparency and TRUE for  AlphaBlend

but mostly setting `WindowState:=wsMaximized;` and `visible:=FALSE;`
then by whatever the taskbar position would be, just get the top\left\width\height of that form

then just adjust your application position by this reference;

Comment: What happens when the taskbar is auto-hidden?

Comment: the OS seem to work it's logics as to get its hands on other window like programs with the caption bar and such; then updates it; who made the OS would change it at any moment, so as far the program are not censored by this logic, it is not about specific things that are others project; like the taskbar; it also fails [if] other programs is taking working space of the desktop; it is really not any of a much;